# Word separator in powershell

Tags: powershell, namespaces

I need to open a folder on a FTP server. The folder name [DAILY Files Folder] has SPACE between the words. If I try it in CMD I can use double quotes and it works. but in power shell I need the double quotes to run the actual command! does anyone know how can I add the space in my folder name without using double quotes?

```
$cmd = @(
"cd /DAILY Files Folder",
"put $file",
"bye"
)
[String]($cmd | & $program -pw $pass "$user@$hst" 2>&1)
```

Comment: Use single quotes within the double quotes? Or use double double quotes such as: `"cd ""/DAILY Files Folder"""` to send the command `cd "/DAILY Files Folder"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape nested double quotes with backticks (`` ` ``):

```
$cmd = @(
"cd `"/DAILY Files Folder`"",
"put $file",
"bye"
)
[String]($cmd | & $program -pw $pass "$user@$hst" 2>&1)
```

or use single quotes as the outer quotes if you don't use variables inside the string:

```
$cmd = @(
'cd "/DAILY Files Folder"',
"put $file",
'bye'
)
[String]($cmd | & $program -pw $pass "$user@$hst" 2>&1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the back tick character (`) to escape each space:

```
DAILY` Files` Folder
```